# How do I clone/copy build definitions from TFS2010 to TFS2012

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I am under Visual Studio 2008 unfortunately and I know that there is the tfs powertools for later versions of viusual studio. But I am tasked with transferring build definitions from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012. How to do it efficiently?

Comment: I take it the builds are in separate collections?

Comment: Why not install a newer version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @DaveShaw - yes separate collections.

Comment: @aclear16 - unfortunately cant do that right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Clone Build Definition" Power Tool (from TFS2010/12) only works on Build Definitions in the same Team Project, if they are in separate Team Projects, or Collections it is not possible. This would be the case if you used VS2010/12 instead of 2008.

The assumption from Microsoft is most likely that the Build process templates may differ, so copying the definition could fail.